# Connecting to TFS 2010 from Eclipse using Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 SP1: Access Denied

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

I am trying to connect to my company's TFS 2010 server from eclipse using Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 SP1.

I have successfully installed the plugin and am attempting to create the connection to our server through the "Add New Server" dialogue. Entering the server `https://tfs.<ourServer>.com/tfs` along with my Active Directory credentials creates the error:

```
Access denied connecting to TFS server... <server> (authenticating as <DOMAIN>\<user.name>
```

I can connect to this same server from Visual Studio 2010 without a problem using the same credentials, and I can also connect to the web client by browsing the the server using IE.

I have also used the command line tool to define a profile which appears in the Eclipse plugin but creates the same error.

Have I missed something obvious? Is there a setting on the TFS server I need to change?

Comment: I would strongly recommend upgrading to Team Explorer Everywhere 2012.  TEE 2012 is compatible with TFS 2010 servers and includes a number of bugfixes *and* changes the getting started and authentication experience to be much simpler (no need for profiles.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried TEE 2012 and I still cant authenticate with the server. The error is:

`Authorization failure connecting to 'https://<ourServer>/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx' (authenticating as <Domain>\<user.name>)
Enter password for https://<ourServer>.com/tfs/` 

It feels like I need to authenticate here not as an AD user but with the server itself, although this could be wrong.

I can browse to the URL in the message and can see the service's manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but changing the Eclipse proxy to native solved the issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have since given up trying and have just used the TFS command line, although I am no longer using Eclipse for development anyway. Hopefully this works for somebody but as I cant test it now I can't mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect successfully if you use the URL of your Team Project Collection, for example:

```
http://tfs.mydomain.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Comment: This behaviour is a little strange. The URL set in Visual studio is
`https://tfs.<ourDomain>.com/tfs/<companyName>%20software`

That is with the %20 space char in the URL. When I attempt to go to this URL in IE I am prompted for my username/password which I type in, but then I get a 404 error. 

I can however go straight to
`https://tfs.<ourDomain>.com/tfs/`

in IE and it logs in successfully and I get the choice of which project I can connect to (of the ones I have the rights to see).

Is the space in the domain the problem? Why does it connect with the extra path in VS but not IE?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know, this sounds like something that would require Fiddler, but does appending the collection name work in TEE?

Comment: In TEE with collection name I get `The SOAP endpoint http://...Registration.asmx could not be contacted: http 404`.

I will try tomorrow to create a new collection with no space in the name to see if that fixes the problem.
Thanks

Comment: For anyone finding this post in future the discussion is continued at: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/d091d804-1114-4c5e-8fdc-534036116d83/#d091d804-1114-4c5e-8fdc-534036116d83)